# Use a batch file to control monitor position?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, batch, resolution

Windows 10 has a way to customize your display settings with the physical order of your multiple monitors, in the pictures below you will see what I mean if you don't know already. I want to use a batch file or another program to toggle between the two monitor orders below. I've looked around and been unable to find any information on this. I want the batch file/program to toggle between these two settings:

Monitor order left to right 2-1-3

Monitor order left to right 3-2-1

If you have found any programs that are able to accomplish this at the click of a button, please link me.

context: I play a game called Counter-Strike: Global Offensive (CSGO). I run the game at a resolution of 1280x1024 stretched on a 1920x1080 monitor that is on the left side of my 3 monitor setup. Running a game in a lower resolution than what I usually run the monitor at causes the windows on the other monitors to displace in compensation for the lost real-estate. The only fix there seems to be for this phenomenon is to have the game monitor on the right side of the setup, and I can't move it there physically. This means that the way my mouse moves across monitors is not physically correct and I want it to be correct.

[This image explains it better than that ^](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UekU.png)

Comment: Note that anomalies may occur when you alter both display settings (windows default ones) and vendor specific driver settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up figuring it out thanks to [Curtis](https://superuser.com/users/497467/curtis). I used [Display Changer](http://12noon.com/?page_id=80) to get the displays to, well, change. The batch files call

I wrote a python script that makes two batch files, and decides which to run based on the number in state.txt.

```
    #matthew blaire
    #6/29/2016
    import os
    from subprocess import call

    userpath = os.path.expanduser("~/Documents")
    filepath = userpath + "/csgo monitor changer"
    normalpath = filepath + "/normal.bat"
    statepath = filepath + "/state.txt"
    csgopath = filepath + "/csgo.bat"
    try:
            ProgramFilesPath = os.path.expandvars("%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%")
    except:
            ProgramFilesPath = os.path.expandvars("%PROGRAMFILES%")
    ProgramFilesPath = ProgramFilesPath + "\\12noon Display Changer\\dc64cmd.exe\""

    if not os.path.exists(filepath): #checks if the filepath exists
            os.makedirs(filepath) #makes it if it doesn't exist already, also makes the files below if they don't already exist

            state = open(statepath, "w")
            state.write("0")
            state.close()

            csgo = open(csgopath, "w")
            csgo.write("\"" + ProgramFilesPath + " -monitor=\"\\\\.\\DISPLAY3\" -more -lx=-1920\n")
            csgo.write("\"" + ProgramFilesPath + " -monitor=\"\\\\.\\DISPLAY2\" -apply -lx=-3840\n")
            csgo.close()

            normal = open(normalpath, "w")
            normal.write("\"" + ProgramFilesPath + " -monitor=\"\\\\.\\DISPLAY2\" -more -lx=1920\n")
            normal.write("\"" + ProgramFilesPath + " -monitor=\"\\\\.\\DISPLAY3\" -apply -lx=3840\n")
            normal.close()

    state = open(statepath, "r")
    if state.read() == "0":
            state.close()
            state = open(statepath, "w")
            call(normalpath)
            state.write("1")

    else:
            state.close()
            state = open(statepath, "w")
            call(csgopath)
            state.write("0")
    state.close()
```

The batch scripts:

csgo.bat:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\12noon Display Changer\dc64cmd.exe" -monitor="\\.\DISPLAY3" -more -lx=-1920
"C:\Program Files (x86)\12noon Display Changer\dc64cmd.exe" -monitor="\\.\DISPLAY2" -apply -lx=-3840
```

normal.bat:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\12noon Display Changer\dc64cmd.exe" -monitor="\\.\DISPLAY2" -more -lx=1920
"C:\Program Files (x86)\12noon Display Changer\dc64cmd.exe" -monitor="\\.\DISPLAY3" -apply -lx=3840
```

state.txt:

```
0 or 1 here
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Display Changer from [here](http://12noon.com/?page_id=80). You will want to look at the **-left | -right | -top | -bottom | -above | -below** parameters.

I took this answer from a similar question: [Change Display Arrangement via Batch/Command Line on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/394601/change-display-arrangement-via-batch-command-line-on-windows-7) if it doesn't work, their are other answers you may want to look into.