# Turn off single screen in Windows 10 multiscreen environment using BAT file

Tags: windows-10

I'm trying to set up a couple shortcuts to put on my Start menu. Since I sometimes use one of the screens for other devices, I'm looking for a quick way to disable that screen in Windows 10 without navigating through configuration menus.

However, the options I have found only turn off the screen until I move the mouse or use the keyboard (both NirCMD and the powersell command, explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30009781/turn-off-window-screen-using-matlab-function), do this). What I want to know is if there is a way to apply the options, highlighted in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFEqQ.png), through commands only. These allow you to make the video output only go through one of the screens and to extend the screens (default option), which would be the shortcuts I want to create.

Comment: see https://superuser.com/q/394601/992527

Comment: BTW: You could have found this with a Google search for keywords "windows display settings command line"

Comment: Today I learned that Duckduckgo sucks at looking into StackExchange. I'll use Google from now on. Thank you!!