# Shortcut to set screen resolution

Tags: windows-xp, shortcuts, resolution

My mom-in-law likes to have her screen set to the lowest possible resolution so that everything is bigger. When I have occasion to use her computer I have to change it to make it usable. The problem is I often forget to restore the settings, which has... consequences.

Is there some way I can put a one-click shortcut on her desktop which will set the resolution to what she wants?

Comment: I don't have XP so I'm not sure if this is doable, but you can give it a try. There are set of command prompt utilities that extend the windows command line capabilities. I found `NirCmd` by googling. You can install it, write a batch file and put a shortcut of that batch on your desktop. But again, I'm not sure how effective are these tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a commandline tool like [QRes.exe](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Video/Other-VIDEO-Tools/QRes.shtml) and create a shortcut to it that passes the resolution you want. So one shortcut per resolution.

Place QRes.exe wherever you like, and place the shortcut on the desktop, then edit the shortcut to include the resolution.

It will look something like this:

```
"C:\Path\To\QRes.exe" /x:800 /y:600
```

(this works only on windows btw, but something similar could probably be found for most OS's)

Comment: Looks like QRes is only available for 32-bit Windows.  It complained when I ran it on 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

To put a one-click shortcut on your Windows desktop which will set the resolution:

- download nircmd 64-bit from https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html
- extract the files to your desktop or wherever you want
- right-click nircmd.exe
- create a shortcut
- open shortcut properties
- edit the path like this `PATH_TO_FILE/nircmd.exe setdisplay 1920 1080 32` [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmZA5.png)
- save changes, voila you have a shortcut to change your resolution

Tested on Windows 10 64bit.

Thanks to harrymc, see his answer here: [Any way of changing Windows screen resolution via command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/89302/any-way-of-changing-windows-screen-resolution-via-command-line)