# Change Windows Resolution for Certain Program

Tags: windows-7, resolution, gaming

So, I'm trying to run a game, and it only supports the resolution of `1280x768` (as well as a few lower ones) and my laptop (Windows 7) supports that resolution, as well as my normally used one of `1366x768`. Essentially the question is is there some sort of program or hack that will automatically change my windows resolution when that program is being run? Or perhaps even when it is only in focus?

If needed, my graphics card is a Nvidia GeForce 710M with latest windows 7 drivers installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a simple `.bat` batch script file that executed a command-line resolution switcher like [QRes](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Video/Other-VIDEO-Tools/QRes.shtml) and then started your game. If you run the game with a `start /wait <path_to_the_game.exe>` command, you could also add something following that which would switch back to your preferred resolution when the game was over using the same utility.

See [Any way of changing Windows 7 screen resolution via command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/89302/any-way-of-changing-windows-7-screen-resolution-via-command-line) for a little bit more about QRes.

Comment: Thanks. Another solution might be to use a utility called [Display Changer](http://12noon.com/?page_id=80) which can switch resolution, and then optionally start a program and then change the resolution back after it finishes.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the scaling options in the nvidia control panel.

Display>>Adjust Desktop Size and Position>>Scaling Tab

Select Aspect ratio.

Now you'll get black bars on the left and right. Alternatively look on http://www.wsgf.org/ for any hacks for your game.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Res-o-matic does exactly what you want
[enter link description here](https://www.ghacks.net/2008/02/29/change-display-resolutions-automatically/)
http://www.bcheck.net/apps/#reso