# How do I fix the display when playing a game on Virtual CloneDrive?

Tags: virtual-machine, gaming

I've downloaded Virtual CloneDrive to play an old PC game from 2000. When I start up the game on VCD the menu looks fine, but once I start the game itself the display is condensed to maybe 1/4th of the screen with black borders on both sides. I've looked everywhere for a fix but the only information I've been able to find is that someone thought this was called "pillar boxing" but I can't seem to find anything anywhere about "pillar boxing." I'm not sure if I need to download a specific driver for this or what, any help at all is appreciated, I'm new to this so the process of troubleshooting is still very interesting to me. Thanks.

Comment: This is likely nothing to do with VCD... what resolution is your screen, what resolution is the game starting in, and can you share a screenshot (if it shows the issue) or photo?

Comment: ... what OS are you running, and what OS was the game built for? Have you tried a compatibility mode, or a virtual machine?

Comment: Yes, @Attie is 100% correct (no big suprise.. Attie is bada$$).  "Back in the day", games were written for fixed resolutions (and mostly still are.. except at 1080 or 4k).. One major difference is that back then, most monitors were CRT and didn't really have a fixed resolution.. they simply got scaled or did the ugly "border thing".  You probably aren't going to "fix" the game.. but you might be able to force your setup to change resolution while the game is playing.  See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/632031/change-windows-resolution-for-certain-program) SU post.