# New screen: resolution so small I can't uninstall/reinstall drivers

Tags: display, resolution

Trying to set up an HDMI TV as the *only* screen on a Windows XP box, replacing an old monitor. The problem is, plugging the TV into the video card, the default resolution is so small that I can't actually access the part of the Catalyst driver screen that changes the screen resolution. I've tried the Catalyst installer to uninstall the driver, but same issue: the actual app screen is larger than my screen, and won't allow resizing, so I can't see the part of the screen that allows me to advance through the installer/uninstaller.

None of these apps can be resized vertically, which means I can never shrink them to the point where I can drag them onto the screen to access the parts of the screen that I need.

I've tried Driver Fusion to uninstall the drivers as well: same problem. I can see the top half of the app screen, but since I can't access the bottom half, I can't ever click "OK" or "Apply", so I can't uninstall the drivers.

Since I can't access either the control center or the installer, I can't change the screen resolution. The default Windows "Properties" from the desktop doesn't let me change the resolution. What's next?

Comment: It seems a little hit and miss, but you might try proceeding through the dialogue by pressing "enter" - and cycling controls with "tab" if your focus wasn't already on the "OK" button. Trial and error?

Comment: Why can't you change the resolution slightly before you connect it to the tv.  You just need it large enough to change it.  Its possible, depending on the hardware, what you want might not be possible.

Comment: Have you tried using Alt+Spacebar to bring up the window's system menu?  That should allow you to manipulate the window.

Comment: @Xyon: Trial and error worked to remove the driver, but something about the reinstalled Catalyst driver itself is forcing the TV to boot into a ridiculously small resolution. I can't even see the resolution values on the Catalyst options screen but might try to fool it. Ramhound, this is the only screen -- I can't adjust the resolution b/c there's no other screen to change the resolution with. rrirower, I'll give it a shot, thanks.

Comment: Does the XP box have an HDMI connector or are you using some type of add-on converter?  Try going directly to the BIOS settings before bootup.  That doesn't use the AMD driver.  Verify that it displays in a "normal size".  Try starting in safe mode and see if you can run msconfig; try disabling the catalyst control center.  Did you download and install CCC from the AMD web site?  There are compatibility problems with systems of that era.  Download the driver from the computer manufacturer's web site.  And I just noticed that this is several yrs old and likely overtaken by events.

Comment: Can you post an answer of how you solved the problem?

Comment: I honestly can't really remember now -- I think in the end I wound up upgrading the video card on another box in the house, the TV computer inherited the other computer's card, and it worked out okay. I'm on to a totally different microform box attached to the TV now, though.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to my comment, you might also try this utility from right here:

[Any way of changing Windows screen resolution via command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/89302/any-way-of-changing-windows-7-screen-resolution-via-command-line)

That should allow you to change the resolution from the command prompt: use <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open the run dialogue if you can't see your start menu.

Answer (score 0):

**First suggestion**: I think you might try messing up the orientation to portrait on your desktop, then click reinstall button.

**Second suggestion**: If previous suggestion doesn't work, and portrait isn't enough, mess up the orientation to portrait like suggestion 1, but this time you have to uncheck hide resolution that tv can't display but graphics card can or something, then, increase the resolution tremendously until you could click the reinstall button.

**Third suggestion**: If suggestion 2 doesn't work, portrait mode and choosing highest resolution isn't enough, this is the only suggestion or I can't think of anything else to suggest. Mess up the orientation to portrait, as in suggestion 1 and 2, this time you have to buy a better graphics card (which will take 3 to 5 days to arrive) which can support at least 1024x768. Nvidia control panel is 1000x750 resolution, so having 800x600 will overlap. After your graphics card has arrived, uncheck hide resolution that tv can't display but graphics card can, then you will find anything higher than 1024x768.

**Fourth suggestion**: If suggestion 3 doesn't work, try this easy suggestion. Try messing up with the zoom of the webpage, from 100 percent to 50 percent, and try uninstall/reinstall drivers. But, if your resolution is something like 400x240, this won't work, try the fifth suggestion that I'll be coming up with.

**Fifth suggestion**: If suggestion 4 doesn't work, mess up the zoom, as in suggestion 4, but this time, select the highest you get by checking show all modes. If it is 800x600, and native is 1024x768, in some advanced monitors, it might be successful if you pan the visible part of the screen as showing in 1024x768.

I suggest you follow the suggestions in order, until you can finally uninstall/reinstall drivers.

Comment: Like I said before, ask mattshepard to follow these suggestions in order.