# How to change display settings to mirroring in Windows 8 from command line?

Tags: windows-8, display-settings

I need to change the display settings in Windows 8, but I cannot use the Control Panel and I must use the command line. My question is, how do I set the displays to mirror each other instead of expanding the desktop, all via the CLI? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found that the answers in this post for Windows 7 will more than likely work just fine for Windows 8. [Any way of changing Windows screen resolution via command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/89302/any-way-of-changing-windows-7-screen-resolution-via-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

Not natively, but as Windows Champ has noted, this question has been asked and answered elsewhere, the consensus is that there are small executables that can be called from the CLI that will allow this.