# How to set screen resolution in Java arguments

Tags: windows-8.1, java, resolution, minecraft

As the title states, how do I set a java argument to set my PC resolution to 1200x800? For example, in Minecraft (lol) there is an option to set JAVA arguments in the profile launcher. I know Minecraft has a way to set launcher size, but it causes a smaller window inside of my PC. I want to change my PC resolution, not Minecraft, through java arguments. That's why I'm posting this in Super user, because its more of a java problem.

Comment: The program must support this in order to do this.  How you do it with a program that does support it is program specific.  But it would only effect the resolution of the program.  **Minecraft cannot set the desktop resolution on a Windows machine.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way of changing Windows 7 screen resolution via command line?](http://superuser.com/questions/89302/any-way-of-changing-windows-7-screen-resolution-via-command-line)

Comment: @Ramhound I know Minecraft cant change the resolution but I want to know if JAVA can, in the JVM arguments?

Comment: Java cannot just change the desktop resolution in Windows.  A java application, I suppose could manipulated Windows, but your not dealing with a java application that can do that.

Comment: There are no JVM arguments to change the screen resolution. See [JVM Options List - still being maintained post Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7833209)

Comment: http://reins.altervista.org/java/A_Collection_of_JVM_Options_MP.html

Comment: Answer for your question is [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225113/change-screen-resolution-in-java).