# Quick switching between monitor resolution/refresh rate settings in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, display, resolution, refresh-rate

I have a display (LG C9) which I have attached to my Windows 10 PC via HDMI. It has the capability of running at 1080p and 120hz, or at 2160p and 60hz, among many other modes that I have no use for.

In order to switch between them, I currently have to:

1. open up display settings
2. click on advanced display settings
3. open up the device adapter properties
4. choose "List All Modes"
5. scroll through the long and cluttered list to find the one setting I'm looking for
6. confirm the change

It's not a *huge* burden, but I often end up sitting on one setting instead of going back and forth like I'd like to because of this. Is there a way to perform this action quicker, and possibly bind it to a key stroke? I'm not against using third-party software such as AutoHotKey to get the job done.

Comment: There are a number of third-party tools, such as *Resolution*, https://sourceforge.net/projects/resolution/ , As with *any* third-party tool, check it at VirusTotal.com before use; some other tools showed as suspicious.

Comment: Can you provide us info with which two resolutions you would like to switch between?

Comment: @KalamalkaKid It's in the post, 1920x1080 120hz and 2160x3840 60hz are the two modes that I use and would like to toggle between.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thanks for the recommendation! This does make it a bit simpler, as it skips most of the menu navigation. But it still requires me to fumble through the big disorganized list of options when I only use two, there's no option to set a hotkey or save favorite resolutions, and it seems to run as a daemon instead of changing the resolution at the source. If there's nothing better then I guess this is fine, but I was hoping for something a little more convenient. Thanks again though!

Comment: @AlexanderJ93 ive written a pretty comprehensive answer that includes a custom script for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a free Windows utility that should be able to get the job done called [QRes](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qres/files/qres/). You can use the CMD to change to any of the supported resolutions, therefore you will be able to create a **.bat** file to switch between the two resolutions:

Once Qres is installed do the following to create a simple .bat file:

**1 -** Open notepad, create a new file and copy and paste the following command::

```
%homepath%\Downloads\QRes\QRes.exe /x:1920 /y:1080
```

In the command above make sure to enter the correct path for the QRes.exe file, and enter a supported width (x) and height (y) pixel resolution. For example, 1366 x 768, 1440 x 900, 1680 x 1050, 1920 x 1080, 2560 x 1440, etc.

**2 -** Click the File menu and select the 'Save A's option.

**3 -** Save the batch file with a descriptive name and a **.bat** file extension.

After you complete the steps, double-click the batch file and the screen resolution should change automatically without the need for extra steps. You can create a second batch file with the alternative resolution and switch between the two resolutions with each separate batch file, or if you need to change the display resolution constantly then you could write something with a toggle using [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/):

An example of an AutoHotKey script in conjunction with Qres might look something like this:

```
#a::
    toggle += 1 ; This increments toggle state (so values after execution of this line will be either 0 or 1)
    if (toggle = 0)
    {
        Run %homepath%\Downloads\QRes\QRes.exe /x:3840 /y:2160
    }
    else if (toggle = 1)
    {
        Run %homepath%\Downloads\QRes\QRes.exe /x:1920 /y:1080
        toggle :=  -1 ; set to -1 so on next run it will end up being 0
    }
Return
```

This script would use Windows A <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> but could be changed to whatever you like (preferably something that Windows doesnt already use). Again, the path to Qres would need to be inputted to the correct path.

There is more documentation on the use of Qres [here](https://pureinfotech.com/change-screen-resolution-command-line-windows-10/). (some source of this question from that site).

**Alternatively**, you could use the freeware tool [NirCmd](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html). Example of usage:

```
nircmd.exe setdisplay 1920 1080 24
```

This changes the display to a resolution of 1920 x 1080 with a 24 bit color depth. You could use NirCmd in conjuction with AutoHotKey as shown above to have a functioning toggle.

There are a lot of good solutions on Super User in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/89302/any-way-of-changing-windows-screen-resolution-via-command-line/89360#89360) as well, but I think what I have provided will suffice.